# How to get strings from a .txt file each 24 hours?

Tags: php

I have a script that is going to show each 24 hour a coupon (discount) code from a .txt file and this .txt file is containing this values:

```
today10
today15
today20
august10
august15
august20
```

And I want my .php script be able to each 24 hours (or even less) and at 9 P.M. every night shows a random string of the given strings in a file called discounts.txt

I've googled and only found [this](https://www.codespeedy.com/get-random-text-by-line-number-from-a-text-file-in-php/) link which shows a random string every time is refreshed. And also this link does not work as I expect, in which case if I use that, almost none of the discount codes users enter would not work.

Could you help me what should I do in this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Write a cron job that runs every day and changes the .txt file.

Comment: Do you need the coupons to repeat?

Comment: @JakubHarabiš only at each 24 hours I need to show a different coupon to users to purchase by. It doesn't matter if the other day a repeated coupon is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can run randomize script from cron once per X h.
   That script should random number (coupon) and save in separate file  e.g. (coupon.txt) that you can display/load in each request

   echo file_get_contents('coupon.txt');

Using cron is better solution.

2. Same but without cron. Your script check if file coupon.txt is older than X h
   if yes then create new content of these file.

To check file data:

```
    if (time() - filemtime ( 'coupon.txt' ) > 86400) {
 // here random coupon and save to file
}
```

And use  echo file_get_contents('coupon.txt'); to display.

Working Example:

```
<?php
   if (!file_exists('coupon.txt') OR time() - filemtime ( 'coupon.txt' ) > 100) {
$coupons  = file('discounts.txt');
shuffle($coupons);
$coupon = $coupons[0];
     file_put_contents ('coupon.txt', $coupon);
    }
else {
$coupon = file_get_contents('coupon.txt');
}
echo 'Coupon is:' . $coupon;
?>
```

Refresh this few times. after 100 s will change. 
Remember that such a script can generate the same coupon twice in a row. If you do not want to repeat it, you must use a different algorithm or delete the coupon used from the discounts.txt file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that does not work because every time I refresh the page, different string is shown.

Comment: Every time is show Time is: TIMESTAMP and also it overwrites the latest timestamp to my file. I have modified it somehow but still not working. Thanks for the cooperation.

Comment: This is only example of idea not fully working mechanism. But Timestamp wuthin 10 sec shouldn't change. If you want longer period then change > 10 for example to > 100  or 86400 (=24h)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need the coupons to repeat you can use this rather crude solution:
You only have to define first day into variable $start.

```
$start = "2019-08-23";
$key = round((time() - strtotime($start)) / (60 * 60 * 24));
$counponsData = file_get_contents("coupons.txt", true);
$coupons = explode(PHP_EOL, $couponsData);

if(isset($coupons[$key])){
    echo $coupons[$key];
} else {
    echo "No more coupons";
}
```

As mentioned, the coupons don't repeat - that means, you have to add enough coupons for the days you want the code to be running

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it only shows No more coupons. I have reduced the time but not yet working.

Comment: Try to set the date to 2019-08-23. Is your file formated ecactly as your example (every coupon on 1 line)?